# Boolean operations on Konva Shapes

Tags: canvas, konvajs

I was wondering how I can do boolean operations on Konva.js?
I'd like to subtract an Konva.Line from a Konva.Rect.

Are there any build-in functions for this, or do I need an outside library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in function for boolean operation on shapes in Konva.

But you can use group + caching + globalCompositeOperation as a workaround.

1. Draw rectangle
2. Draw a line with globalCompositeOperation = destination-out to "cut" it from rect
3. Put both rectangle and line into grou
4. Cache the group, so globalCompositeOperation of a line doesn't effect the rest of your drawings.

```js
const stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight
});

const layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

const group = new Konva.Group({ draggable: true });
layer.add(group);

const shape = new Konva.Rect({
  x: 50,
  y: 50,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fill: 'green'
});
group.add(shape);

const line = new Konva.Line({
  x: 50,
  y: 50,
  points: [20, 20, 50, 20, 50, 50],
  closed: true,
  fill: 'black',
  globalCompositeOperation: 'destination-out'
})
group.add(line);

group.cache();
```

```html
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@^9/konva.min.js"></script>
  <div id="container"></div>
```